# PHP: Improve speed returning Mesh terms from Entrez database (Pubmed)

Tags: php, performance, pubmed

I want to extract Mesh terms from search results in the Pubmed database. I am using php.

I made a script that works but it is very slow. It opens each article, parses the XML and retrieves the mesh terms. The "fopen" function is the slow part.

```
$url= $base."efetch.fcgi?db=$db&id=$id&rettype=abstract";    
$opts = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method' => "GET",
    'header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$fp = fopen($url,'r',false,$context);
$output=stream_get_contents($fp);
```

The script opens for each article a big xml file:
http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=19616537&retmode=xml

Is there a way to retrieve only Mesh terms, or at least a smaller part of the xml? Or load only half of the file?

Thank you

---

update:
I got some improvement. Using efetch with `retmode=text` and `rettype=medline` reduced the download for one file from 15 kb to 4kb. I also bundled all downloads to reduce the amount of requests.

It now takes 4.8s to load 500 results.

I still want it faster.

Does anyone have some tips?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are your limits and goal. But if you are quering the whole database then I would try the other way around. Query database to list articles for every known MeSH term. As far as I know there are only ["27,149 descriptors in 2014 MeSH"](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/pubs/factsheets/mesh.html), so you need to send less then 30 thousands queries to get results for whole database. You can achieve it using  [Europe PMC RESTful Web Service](http://europepmc.org/RestfulWebService#search).